# Is it possible to dynamically populate the list of products for in-app purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've already have the Android app and the server with the content. Now for the iOS app I'm looking into in-app purchase. From what I'm reading I understand I must follow the "Server Product Model", not the "Built-In Product Model". Now for the question:

Will I have to add every product (there's 100s) twice, once on my server and once on Apples web site; or is it possible to send the product to Apple as well when adding it to my server (or have Apple add it to my server when I add it to Apple)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for registering in-app purchases to Apple, and Apple doesn't look at your server. The only solution is to add manually new products on your server, and in Itunes Connect.